# How can i make an item powered by wall outlet powered by usb?

Tags: usb

Is there anyway of powering the lights without splicing wires to convert the wall plug powered device to a usb powered device?

I want to run some lights for my coffee table. They are powered by wall outlet and I dont want to run a cord from the wall to the coffee table. Not sure if this would work.

I was thinking that, I have a portable power bank that I could run the lights off that. Only problem is the power bank only has a place to plug in a usb device not a wall powered device. Ive looked for a device on the internet to convert the wall plug to usb so I could power the lights for my coffee table.I found this: 
 http://www.nextwarehouse.com/item/?1312964_g10e

Was thinking about plugging the cord into the plug outlet and the power bank into the usb outlet below.

Will that work? Or is there another device that will work? Or even a better way to go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Input Voltage - 110 V AC" "Output Voltage - 5 V DC" Uh...

Comment: if you replaced all the lamps and spliced some cables together, maybe...

Comment: Yep, run an extension cable into the coffee table with a phone charger on the end. This question has nothing to do with electrical design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no widely popular inexpensive solution for this specific problem.  Realistically you should just get some USB powered lights, 12v lights, or better yet lights with their own rechargeable battery.  Consider camping / recreational vehicle suppliers.

If you were actually going to try to put something like this together, what you would need would be an `inverter` to generate a reasonable substitute for mains power, running off a battery.

You can get automotive inverters intended to run off something like a car battery, but you don't want that inside so you'd need to substitute a sealed gel cell, and then come up with a charger for that in turn.

A computer UPS would have most of what you need, but these typically are only designed to run for a few minutes and may not have the efficiency at light load to run just your lights for longer; worse, they typically have a very loud and annoying alarm buzzer when supplying power which you would need to disable.

It's vaguely possible some camping, professional photography, or other source sells a mains output powerbank, but it's likely to be larger and heavier than a typical USB powerbank, and a far, far, far more expensive specialty item.